# How do I get the pageobject id of a slide based on its text using google slide api

Tags: python, google-api, google-slides-api

I need to retrieve the page object id of a slide in Google slides based on text located in the slide. I was wondering if there was a way to do this using google slide API for python.

Answer (score 1):

This short code should explain how to extract all relevant information from all the slides including slide objectid.

```
function logSlidesObjectIdAndElements() {
  var presentationId = 'ACTUAL_ID';
  var presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
  var slides = presentation.slides;
  Logger.log('The presentation contains %s slides:', slides.length);
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(
      '- Slide with objectid:%s Slide#%s contains %s 
       elements.',slides[i].objectId,i + 1,
       slides[i].pageElements.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an existing implementation. I can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/) that you need to get the **`objectID`** by supplying the needed **`presentationID`** and not the `"content"`.

For example in the `Try it` section of the [Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get), you need to supply the presentationID before you can achieve the response containing your needed information like `"objectId"` and `"content"`.

```
{
  "presentationId": "000AAAAAAAAA_AAA0AA00AA00A0A0AAAA00AAAA7AAA",
  "pageSize": {
    "width": {
      "magnitude": 9144000,
      "unit": "EMU"
    },
    "height": {
      "magnitude": 5143500,
      "unit": "EMU"
    }
  },
  "slides": [
    {
      "objectId": "p",
      "pageElements": [
        {
          "objectId": "i0",
          "size": {
            "width": {
              "magnitude": 3000000,
              "unit": "EMU"
            },
            "height": {
              "magnitude": 3000000,
              "unit": "EMU"
            }
          },
          "transform": {
            "scaleX": 2.8402,
            "scaleY": 0.6842,
            "translateX": 311708.35000000003,
            "translateY": 744575,
            "unit": "EMU"
          },
          "shape": {
            "shapeType": "TEXT_BOX",
            "text": {
              "textElements": [
                {
                  "endIndex": 6,
                  "paragraphMarker": {
                    "style": {
                      "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "endIndex": 6,
                  "textRun": {
                    "content": "My ID\n",
                    "style": {}
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
```